# Pycharm don´t show me an array

Tags: python, arrays, pycharm

import numpy as np

```
my_list = [1,2,3]

x = np.array(my_list)

print(x)
```

I get back:

```
[1 2 3]
```

but it should be:

```
array([1,2,3])
```

Comment: it is an array, `print(type(x), repr(x))`

Comment: "but it should be" Why? You can't assume that an object's `__str__` implementation will be the same as its `__repr__` implementation (and, in most cases, it won't)

Answer (score 0):

By default, when giving a `numpy` array as argument to `print()`, the `list` that the `numpy` array contains is printed.